# How do I use Facebook credits in Playfish's Restaurant City?

Tags: facebook, restaurant-city

How do I use Facebook credits in a game like Playfish's Restaurant City?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert Facebook credits (FbC) into your game's currency...

1. **Launch the game** you want to play.
2. Once there, that game has some type of currency and a means to add more of that game's currency.  Restaurant City uses coins, and in the upper left hand corner of the screen is a button that says "Add Coins".  **Press the Add Coins button.**
3. The next screen allows you to add coins (or bucks, or horseshoes, or whatever that game uses) via several options (VISA, PayPal, and **Facebook Credits**).
4. **Follow the prompts** to convert FbC into that game's currency.

This one took me a while to figure out.  All of the sudden a bunch of people got free Facebook Credits and didn't know what to do with them.  Hope this helps!!